# Modify self but with same data type

Tags: ruby

I have a `Bitmap` class (of which I **don't** have the source code) which has a constructor.

I've made my own encryption method for files, and when initializing a Bitmap, it may have to decrypt the file before it can load it. I have a method that does this: `Bitmap::load_png`. It returns a `Bitmap` object.

Now, this project already has hundreds of references to `Bitmap.new`, so I don't want to have to replace every single one (and there are classes that inherit `Bitmap` or check with `.is_a?`, so I can't just replace everything).

For this reason, I want to write something that either initializes the `Bitmap` as normal, or uses `Bitmap::load_png` depending on the amount of arguments given. If there are 2, it should use the original `Bitmap.new`, otherwise, it should use `Bitmap::load_png`.

I'm struggling to figure out how I'd go about doing this. I can't return the result of `Bitmap::load_png` in `def initialize`, because the return value is ignored.
I can't return the value in `def self.new` either, because that will also override classes that inherit it.

Here's some reference code:

```
class Bitmap
  alias old_init initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    if args.size == 2
      old_init(*args)
      # old_init modifies self's data
    else
      Bitmap::load_png(*args)
      # ::load_png returns a new Bitmap object
    end
  end
end
```

I really don't know how I could make this work. I don't want to spend four days digging through all my code to look for references to `Bitmap.new` and replace them with, say, `Bitmap.get` (this would work).

So I guess what I want is a method like `self.replace(value)` for this `Bitmap` class. I don't know what and where the data is stored, though. I don't know what variables or methods it uses.

Comment: How do you not have the source code to a Ruby project? Is this a compiled extension?

Comment: Can you subclass this and give the subclass the ability to differentiate instead? That's usually less messy than monkeypatching the main class. Overriding `initialize` isn't going to work, you need to alter how the class `new` method operates.

Comment: @tadman This is Ruby 1.9.2 from RPG Maker XP. It loads a library from a DLL called RGSS 3, of which there is no source code.
I'm not sure how subclassing will help since everything everywhere uses `Bitmap`.

Comment: Oh, wow, that's way out of date as far as Ruby's concerned, but if that's the pickle you're in then so be it. You're going to have to patch `self.new`, not `initialize`, because once you're down the `initialize` road you can't switch objects.

Comment: I've come to that conclusion too, and I did manage to make `Bitmap` itself functional by modifying `self.new`. I thought I was done but, if another class (say, NewClass) inherits it, calling `NewClass.new` returns a Bitmap for some reason (probably because it finds `self.new` in Bitmap so it skips the new class's constructor)
I tried modifying that class to use an `@bmp` variable instead of inheriting `Bitmap`, but I run into countless issues where it's referenced directly. I tried using `method_missing` with bitmap to fix it but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that might work better:

```
class Bitmap
end

module BitmapWrapper
  def self.new(*args)
    case args.size
    when 2
      Bitmap.new(*args)
    else
      Bitmap.load_png(*args)
    end
  end
end

Object.send(:const_set, :CompiledBitmap, Bitmap)
Object.send(:remove_const, :Bitmap)
Object.send(:const_set, :Bitmap, BitmapWrapper)
```

This swaps out the compiled `Bitmap` class with a wrapper that can intermediate. This is pretty dirty, but should work when you have a lot of code referencing Bitmap.

Comment: It's still calling the old Bitmap constructor. I tried adding a debug print statement in this new `def initialize` but it doesn't fire at all.

Comment: Compiled extensions are more annoying to patch, so sometimes subclassing is the only way to go. You can always rename the `Bitmap` class to something else, then swap in your replacement.

Comment: I really hate that it's closed-source, yeah. Also, how'd I rename the class? Assuming you mean programmatically.

Comment: Still not having any luck. I tried swapping some names and methods but to no avail.

Comment: This might be a tough road to go down with the tools you're given. You're going to have to weigh how valuable the encryption part is given how people can rip your assets with screenshots anyway.